# pythonic way to merge 2 lists on multiple keys (without pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

What is the pythonic way to merge 2 lists on multiple keys without using a dictionary nor pandas.

Given:

```
a = [[700,0, 'A'], [700,1, 'B'],[704,0, 'C'],[704,1, 'A'],[709,0, 'A'],[710,0, 'A'],[711,0, 'A']]
b = [[700,0, 'N'], [700,1, 'J'],[711,0, 'W']]
```

And I wish to merge a with b such that the end result would be (note: first and second item = key):

```
[[700, 0, 'A', 'N'],
[700, 1, 'B', 'J'],
[704, 0, 'C', ''],
[704, 1, 'A', ''],
[709, 0, 'A', ''],
[710, 0, 'A', ''],
[711, 0, 'A', 'W']]
```

Today, I'm converting it to a dataframe and back to a list but wonder if there's an easier/pythonic  way to do so. A dictionary on key=i[0] and i[1 would result in a relative long code.

**with Pandas:**

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['id','sq','value'])
df_b = pd.DataFrame(b, columns=['id','sq','ext'])
d = pd.merge(df_a,df_b,left_on=['id','sq'], right_on=['id','sq'], how='outer').fillna('')
d.values.tolist()
```

and I get the desired results but I want to skip the pandas trick.

[image]

Comment: Do you just want to merge them on the first two items (e.g. 700, 0)?

Comment: do you actually need the empty ' ' in the lists if there is no additional value?

Comment: @Chris nope, it can be empty or whatever, preferable anything that is json passable (not nan)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [itertools groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
a = [[700,0, 'A'], [700,1, 'B'],[704,0, 'C'],[704,1, 'A'],[709,0, 'A'],[710,0, 'A'],[711,0, 'A']]
b = [[700,0, 'N'], [700,1, 'J'],[711,0, 'W']]

from itertools import groupby 
result=[]
kf=lambda sl: sl[0:2]

for k,v in groupby(sorted(a+b, key=kf), key=kf):
    result.append(k+[e for y in [sl[2:] for sl in v] for e in y])
```

You can also use the same sort and then use a dict to assemble the sublists and then flatten the key and value into the desired sublists:

```
di={}
for sl in sorted(a+b, key=kf):
    di.setdefault(tuple(sl[0:2]),[]).extend(sl[2:])
    
result=[list(k)+v for k,v in di.items()]
```

In both cases:

```
>>> result
[[700, 0, 'A', 'N'], [700, 1, 'B', 'J'], 
 [704, 0, 'C'], [704, 1, 'A'], 
 [709, 0, 'A'], [710, 0, 'A'], [711, 0, 'A', 'W']]
```

If order is important, you need to use Python 3.6+ for the dict approach or use an OrderedDict for prior versions.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `groupby` with a custom key for this:

```
from itertools import groupby, chain

a = [[700,0, 'A'], [700,1, 'B'],[704,0, 'C'],[704,1, 'A'],[709,0, 'A'],[710,0, 'A'],[711,0, 'A']]
b = [[700,0, 'N'], [700,1, 'J'],[711,0, 'W']]

ab = [*a, *b]

ab = sorted(ab, key=lambda x:x[:2])

grouped = groupby(ab, key=lambda x:x[:2])

output = []
for k, g in grouped:
    output.append(k + [x for x in chain.from_iterable(g) if x not in k])
```

Output

```
[[700, 0, 'A', 'N'],
 [700, 1, 'B', 'J'],
 [704, 0, 'C'],
 [704, 1, 'A'],
 [709, 0, 'A'],
 [710, 0, 'A'],
 [711, 0, 'A', 'W']]
```

Answer (score 3):

there's a kinda simple way to do this with a defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict

res = defaultdict(lambda: ['', ''])

for i, vals in enumerate([a, b]):
    for *key, v in vals:
        res[tuple(key)][i] = v

final_res = [[*k, *v] for k, v in res.items()]
```

Comment: @acushner thanks for your input. +1 The result (res) do not produce the same expected result though (but I know how to take it from here)

Comment: @acushner perfect! thanks. I learned something new.

Answer (score 0):

Sort both lists, then do a pass over one and walk a pointer up the other one to produce the merged list. O(nlogn) complexity.

```
def sortOnFirst2Cols(m):
    return sorted(m, key = lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))

sorted_a = sortOnFirst2Cols(a)
sorted_b = sortOnFirst2Cols(b)

merged = []
p = 0 # pointer in shorter list
for i in range(len(sorted_a)):
    if p >= len(sorted_b): break # we have reached the end of the other arr, no more items to merge

    if sorted_b[p][0] > sorted_a[i][0] or (sorted_b[p][0] == sorted_a[i][0] and sorted_b[p][1] > sorted_a[i][1]): 
        continue # we need to catch up to the pointer in the other arr

    if sorted_b[p][0] == sorted_a[i][0] and sorted_b[p][1] == sorted_a[i][1]:
        merged.append([*sorted_a[i], sorted_b[p][2]]) # splat (*) the arr from a, and merge with the 3rd item in the arr from b
    p+=1

print(merged)
```

It is not super clean. I'm sure the more Pythonic way is to make use of existing `zip` capabilities, or perhaps some method in `itertools`.

*Note: this solution uses the `*` "iterable unpacking operator" as described in [PEP 448](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#whatsnew-pep-448), which requires Python 3.5 or higher. If this is not possible, simply manually create the merged item by using the array literal notation with the 0th, 1th, and 2nd arr items from `sorted_a`.*

Comment: your code doesnt produce the same desired result. Also, as you mentioned, (and I agree), it is inferior to the pandas trick.

Comment: Ok it works now. It doesn't fully satisfy the spec as it only finds the intersection. Other answers in this thread should be better.